# Word Cloud Generator

Tags: d3.js, word-cloud

I'm creating Word Cloud Generator with using [Jason Davies's Word Cloud Generator](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud), but just a way to enter data it also **textarea** that accept just **String** and my problem that, My data enteries are Objects:

```
var data= [{
            "text": "First",
            "size": 12
            }, {
            "text": "Second",
            "size": 35
          }];
```

Now, Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is Solved by using **Generate** function and **Tags** array in ***cloud.js***.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) is pretty clear about how it should be used. The following is adopted from the [example](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/browserify.js).

```
var layout = cloud().words(data);
layout.start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("#container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
      .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
      .style("font-family", "Impact")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```